# How to get the last index of a specific character before a different one

Tags: c#, string, lastindexof

Sorry, It's kinda hard to explain it for me.

I want to get the index of the last *new line* character which placed before a different character in a `C#` application.

for example, I want the index of the `\n` which is placed before `Hi`

```
"\n\n\n\n\nHi\n\n\n"
```

Also I want the first index of `\n` which is placed after `Hi`.

I know [String.LastIndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has multiple ways to use. I just don't know if I can *or how to* use it to get what I want.

**EDIT**

This is what I've came up to so far.

```
int firstIndex=myString.IndexOf("\n")==0 ? 0 : -1;
int secondIndex=myString.Text.Trim().IndexOf("\n");
```

I want to know if there's a better or more standard way to do that.

Comment: Can't you just search for `"\nHi"`?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I don't know what the character after `\n` would be

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried anything at all? Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, with a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Regex.Matches to find the item with pattern. A simple approach can be

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = "\n\nHi\n\n\nTest\nTest";

        var matches = Regex.Matches(input, "\\n");

        for (int index = 0; index < matches.Count - 1; index++)
        {
            var match = matches[index];

            if (match.Index + 1 != matches[index + 1].Index)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Last Match found at " + match.Index);
                Console.WriteLine("Next first Match found after last item at " + matches[index + 1].Index);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Last Match found at " + matches[matches.Count - 1].Index);
    }
}
```

It print the output as

```
Last Match found at 1
Next first Match found after last item at 4
Last Match found at 6
Next first Match found after last item at 11
Last Match found at 11
```

Answer (score 0):

There lots of ways to skin this cat. Here's one

```
string input = "\n\n\n\n\nHi\n\n\n";
string [] split = input.Split('\n');
int prevN = -1, nextN = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++) {
     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(split[i])) {
        prevN = i - 1;
        nextN = i + split[i].Length;
        break;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(prevN + "-" + nextN);
```

Prints "4-7". Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int index = "\n\n\n\n\nHi\n\n\n".IndexOf("hi", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n\nHi\n\n\n".Split('i')[1].IndexOf("\n") + index);
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n\nHi\n\n\n".Split('i')[1].LastIndexOf("\n") + index);
}
```

Comment: `Hi` just was an example of what could be in the string. I can't predict what the user would input as the string